# overinstall/reinstall/repair Windows 7 and keep old programs and data?

Tags: windows-7, reinstall, windows-7-restore

I have a broken Windows 7 system which does not fully boot. The *system restore* is not working.

I am inexperienced with Windows systems.

**Question:** Is it possible to use a Windows 7 install CD and install it over the old system? Will the data and programs be preserved? Or is there a repair/reinstall/overinstall mode? I haven’t tried it yet, as I don’t want to destroy anything.